# Can we always pull a joint posterior apart?

Tags: probability, bayesian, posterior

If we have a posterior distribution $p(A,B|\theta)$, is it always true that
$p(A,B|\theta) = p(A|\theta)p(B|\theta)?$

Comment: When everything is conditioned on θ, you can basically ignore it. (Or just pretend θ = "the sky is blue".) Is the statement true in that case?

Answer (score 12):

No, it is not. In order for that to be true, $A$ and $B$ should be conditionally independent given $\theta$.